# How to group by similar full-text?

Tags: postgresql

I have [a database of open-source project mentions](https://gitspo.com/analytics). However, a lot of the project mentions are repeating with slight alterations, e.g.

- scandum/quadsort: merge sort on steroids github.com/scandum/quadsort
- scandum/quadsort merge but on steroids github.com/scandum/quadsort
- better merge github.com/scandum/quadsort its merge on steroids!

To make the alerts about project mentions more useful, I would like to remove group identical/ near identical mentions.

If I have 1 mention, I can find similar mentions using tsvector. But how do I go counting the number of ~unique mentions?

Comment: It is hard to group by similarity, because similarity is not transitive: if A is similar to B and B is similar to C, A need not be similar to C. I assume that this is at the heart of your problem.

Comment: You are right... but this gave me an idea for a solution! I could at a time of inserting a record perform a search of similar texts (using tsvector) and if found, assign a shared attribute. Need to test to see how well this would work, but as far as I can think, it would get the desired result.

Comment: Yes, that would be a better solution than trying to group afterwards.